# Why occur C2280 error in list in vector push back?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Here is my code.

```
class Obj
{
    int iNum = 0;
};

vector<list<unique_ptr<Obj>>> vlist;
list<unique_ptr<Obj>> List;
List.push_back( make_unique<Obj>() );
vlist.push_back( List ); // <<--- C2280 Error
```

C2280 “attempting to reference a deleted function”

I read related questions but still cannot solve my problem. I have a doubt regarding the delete function in xmemory file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of c++ are you using?

Comment: do note that [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) _satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable_ and that [list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) requires that _T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible_ (until c++11). Are you sure that you want `unique_ptr`s in a `list`?

Comment: Use `emplace_back` or `std::move`. u ique_ptr is not copyable (for obvious reasons; If you could copy it, it would no longer be *unique*).

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 - C++11. 
I'm not sure I use unique_ptr in a list.

Comment: But I want to use unique_ptr. Is it wrong to use unique_ptr now? shared_ptr is right ?